# Regarding HIVE Table Storage

Tags: hive

Can anyone please help me understanding the below point.

I have created one HIVE table which is not a partition table, but I am working in a 10 node cluster, so in this case will the data of that table (the table is a large table) will be spread across different data nodes??? or will it be there only in one node??

If it spread across different data nodes then how we can see only one file under \hive\warehouse folder?

Also please give little idea how this storage allocated for a partition table.

Comment: Look there http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/hdfs_design.html

Answer (score 0):

The **data for the table** and the **metadata of the table** are different things.

The data for the table, which is basically just a file in HDFS, will be stored as per HDFS rules (that is based on your configuration, a file will be split into n number of blocks and stored distributedly on datanodes). 
In your case the data for one hive table( a file or ay number of files) will be stored distributedly among all the 10 nodes in the cluster.
Also, this distribution is done at the block level and not visible at the user level. 
You can check the number of blocks created for the file int he Web UI easily.

A partitioned table is just like adding another directory inside the table directory in HDFS. So it follows the same rules.